# How do I transverse this binary tree using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, nodes

I am very stuck. I understand recursion, but this project has got me lost.

Basically, this tree takes something like

```
(a(b()())(c(d()())()))
```

and outputs

```
a b 
a c d
```

That being said, every node can have 0, 1, or 2 children. Therefore, if the node contains 0 children, I know that means it's time for recursion to take action & return to the root of the tree and go to the right side of the tree (because it reads the left side first). 
Overall, I am just very confused.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BinaryTreeFinal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tree = scan.nextLine();//correct format : (a()())
        String[] t = splitTree(tree);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
        //System.out.println(tree2("a", "(a(b()())(c(d()())()))"));
    }

    public static String[] splitTree(String tree)
    {
        //expected format
        //(node tree tree)
        //0 1 2-x x-(length-2) length-1
        if(tree.length() <= 2)//tree not long enough to process
            return new String[]{tree};

        String[] temp = new String[3];
        temp[0] = "" + tree.charAt(1);//grab tree node
        tree = tree.substring(2, tree.length()-1);//remove node and outer paren
        int parenCount = 0;//count of open paren
        int endTreeOne = 0;//end of first tree
        for(int i = 0; i < tree.length(); i++)
        {
            if(tree.charAt(i) == '(')
                parenCount++;
            if(tree.charAt(i) == ')')
                parenCount--;
            if(parenCount == 0)
            {
                endTreeOne = i;
                break;//ends for loop early
            }
        }
        temp[1] = tree.substring(0, endTreeOne+1);//left tree
        temp[2] = tree.substring(endTreeOne+1);//right tree
        return temp;
    }
```

This is where the code gets messy:

```
public static char tree2(String root, String path)
{

    int counter = 0;
    String[] trees = splitTree(path);

    if(trees[1].charAt(counter) == '(' && trees[1].charAt(counter++) == ')')
    {
        counter++;
        //return trees[1].charAt(counter);
        return tree2(String, String);
        //System.out.println(trees[1].charAt(counter));


    }
    else 
        //System.out.println(trees[1].charAt(counter));
        return trees[1].charAt(counter);
    //counter++;


}
```

Many thanks, and I am so sorry it's confusing. I don't quite know how to word this.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a binary tree here? Just curious.

Comment: My professor is requiring the binary tree here.

Comment: Ah! Haha I was doing a `Stack`-based approach. Updates soon :)

Comment: I am open to any advice or examples there are!

Comment: There you go, buddy. A `Stack` based approach. Let me think of a tree based approach. Maybe, you will find some ideas based on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little something I wrote up using `Stack`s.

```
Input: `(a(b()())(c(d()())()))`

Output: a b 
        a c d 

Input: `(a(b()())(c(d()())(e)))`

Output: a b 
        a c d 
        a c e
```

As you might understand, I have not thoroughly tested this. Please run a few more tests and see if it is working as required.

Let me put my thought process in a few words. I saw that a `character` was being preceded by a `(`. The `a` or parent portion was getting printed only if there were more children present. So, I thought, whenever a `)` was found, I would check my stack to see if the element on top was a `(`. If yes, great. If not, I would keep popping till I found the matching parenthesis. Once this was done, I knew I had to move to the next line of the console. Then, I would need to keep track of what alphabets I already had in my stack, in the eventuality that they would need to be reprinted as the parents of a new child. So, I did that. When a new child is encountered, the parents are printed and everything appears to be golden. Let me know if it isn't (with the tests it is failing).

```
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
String st = "(a(b()())(c(d()())(e)))";
String parent = null;
for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
    char c = st.charAt(i);

    if (c != ')') {

        // if it is an alphabet
        if (c != '(') {
            // will require printing of parents
            // iff there are more characters to print
            if (parent != null) {
                System.out.print(parent);
                parent = null;
            }
            System.out.print(c + " ");
        }
        stack.push(c);
    } else {
        // is the character on top a matching opening bracket?
        // if it is, then nothing to do, if not 
        char curTop = stack.pop();
        if (curTop != '(')
            while (curTop != '(')
                curTop = stack.pop();
        else
            continue;

        // done working with a character; move to next line
        System.out.println();

        // now, need to reprint the `a` portion 
        // iff more children are present
        Stack<Character> temp = new Stack<Character> ();
        while (!stack.isEmpty())
            temp.push(stack.pop());

        while (!temp.isEmpty()) {
            Character ch = temp.pop();
            if (!(ch == '(' || ch == ')')) {
                // store content
                if (parent == null)
                    parent = "";
                parent += ch + " ";
            }

            stack.push(ch);
        }

    }
}
```